# Low flow rate from shower head

Tags: shower

My master bathroom shower head has very low flow rate. I've changed several heads, and still the flow is low.

I took off the shower handle and the back plate to see if I could adjust the hot and cold water that is coming into the handle. However, there seems to be no set screw that controls the hot or cold water on either side.

I've seen videos online where there should be screws on either side to control temp/flow rate for the cold and hot water coming into the shower and you can adjust it using a screwdriver. But, it seems mine is not setup like that.

So what are my options to increase flow rate? Should change the cartridge then to see if that helps?

By the way home was built in 2005.  Here are a few pictures of what I have:

[image: henter image description here]

[image]

Comment: Has the flow ever been higher? Or has the flow been consistent since you have lived there?

Comment: Is flow still low with no shower head, just bare pipe?

Comment: Your mixer valve might be caput. Find and marks/make on it, and buy replacement cartage.

Comment: I just a did test and the master shower takes about 5.5 minutes to fill a 5 gallon container with no shower head (bare pipe) while the other shower that is in the middle of our upstairs takes about 4 minutes to fill a 5 gallon container. I did not test the 3rd shower that is downstairs. The master shower is the furthest from where the boiler (located in the garage). What do you think of the numbers?

Comment: The flow was OK before and recently it become very slow.

Comment: Check your water at its source can it supply 5 gal in about 2 minutes? If not check into that because if it is not available you cannot get it.

Comment: Flow rate should be equal all though the house, if the pipes are the same size.  The flow rate reduction at one point, would usually mean a partial blockage, either in the valve or the pipe.  Imagine you have one of those anti-scalding valves, so it makes it hard to test if hot or cold is the problem.

Comment: did you shut off the mains between when it flowed well and when it stopped flowing well? sometimes the drop of pressure causes little bits of gunk to become unstuck from crevices, and when the water resumes they can find themselves in valves, heads, cartridges, etc..

Comment: @JoeyDYI, you have a number of questions requiring followup. Please do, and please respond to any answers properly as well. Take the [tour] if you need a refresher.